# How can I calm panicked units?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm playing Ironman Classic and just lost one of my rookies to a plasma pistol in the face. Both of my veterans started freaking out, and shooting at random people.

Is there anything I can do to calm them down before they kill each other?

Comment: I'll add this here since it is a bit of a tangent. My advice is to not waste medpacks on soldiers who are bleeding out. The permanent will decrease makes them too prone to panic and a liability in later missions. Of course, if they die, then they my trigger panic in your other soldiers, so on occasion I do save them only to dismiss them once they heal up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Panic is a one-shot deal. When a unit panics, they react erratically, and lose their next turn.

This means that, in a best case scenario, you will regain control of the panicked soldier on the next turn.

However, XCOM being what it is, your soldiers may panic *again* (the lowered will from having already panicked not helping), with the same unpredictable results.

Late game, the psionic ability "Psychic Inspiration" will remove panic, and re-allow them to take their actions. If cast preemptively, it can often prevent panic from happening in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, if you have any soldiers left standing I would use any and all means necessarily to eliminate threats and hope for the best.  If you can win the mission I think you'll be ok (I had a squad mate bleeding out when I won the mission and he survived.  Wounded, granted).

I've had panicked squaddies calm down.  I can't say whether this was due to morale settling "naturally" or if removing immediate threats helped with this.  I don't know if later-game technology will help with this, but there is nothing I know of in the early game.

@donnniegoat provided a comment highlighting this [PC Gamer article](http://www.pcgamer.com/2012/10/08/xcom-enemy-unknown-guide/2/) about a "Psychic Inspiration" ability that will calm panicked squaddies by boosting willpower and removing panic and mindfray, but unfortunately it won't be available until well into the game.

Answer (score -3):

You can award defender medal, gives an option to be immune to panic.

Comment: I...don't recall this being an actual option in XCOM.

Comment: It's "Never panic as a result of an ally getting wounded or killed," which is a far cry from "Immunity to panic."